# How to remove or hide post title from selected posts

Tags: wordpress

**The case:**

I'm writing product catalog plugin. My plugin is generating product page for every product you add with it. To do so, it's using `wp_insert_post` function, where `'post_type'` is set to `'page'`, and as `'post_content'` I'm using code from genericproductpage.php I've made. It contains some php and a shortcode, that is used to generate product page for given product.

**Question:**

Is there any way to remove or hide page title from final product page (I'm talking about visibility; I do not want to remove page name from database)? I know I can just add `display: none;` to page title class in css, but every theme is using different class naming for it. And I need to find a solution that is **theme independent**. I was thinking also about custom post type, but again I'm not sure if it's even possible to make it completely theme independent. Any ideas if or how I can remove/hide it?

Answer (score 0):

When you [register your custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments), you can declare what it supports. One of the options is also `title`. If you don't declare it the editor will not show `title` and the theme won't be able to render it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [Hide Title](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-title/), that can do this.

- Once activated edit a post/page
- On the right hand side of the screen, there is a tick box with a "Hide Title" heading, that when selected will hide the title.
- Update/publish the post/page.